# Is my proof of uniqueness of limit of sequence correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, propositional-calculus

In order to convince myself, I came up with a truth table logical proof of "uniqueness of limit of sequence".

Following is MY proof. Is everything correct? Does it needs to be modified?

In the truth table, RED shaded row means the truth values in the row is not entirely correct and needs to be ignored. And GREEN shaded row means the entire truth values in the row is correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you choosing $\varepsilon_0$ so that $|l-l'|>2\varepsilon_0$ or $|l-l'|<2\varepsilon_0$? You say one in the faded red box and you say the other after $A\wedge B\wedge C$. Also, it would be simpler to show that for all $\varepsilon>0$, $|l-l'|<\varepsilon$ to get rid of ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry The faded red box one is correct. Let me edit please. Thanks for pointing it out...

Comment: I hope everything is clear after my edit.

Comment: Is anything unclear to anyone now?

Comment: you say $x_n$ cannot lie at two different points in the reason box. What I think you want to say is $x_n$ cannot be in the intersection of two disjoint intervals. If I am reading table $(1)$ correctly, you have $A\wedge B$ and $C$ both being true implying $D$ is true, but directly underneath, you have $A\wedge B$ and $C$ both being true implying $D$ is false. should we just ignore that row, as you said above?

Comment: First we are filling all possible truth values in $A \wedge B$, $C$, $D$. It is given $A \wedge B$ is true. So we have not written the $F$ entry in the $A \wedge B$ coulmn. In $C$ and $D$ coulmns we have written all $T$ and $F$ entries. It is to be noted that when $C$ is false, $D$ is not a proposition.

Comment: ,,, should we just ignore that row, as you said above? YES and that is why that row is shaded in red

Comment: yes then everything looks fine. i like the structure of this argument and how you included the truth tables.

Comment: Thanks..............

Comment: Andrew : Why wouldn't $D$ be a proposition in your linked question? It's a fully formed sentence with no free variables.

Comment: Me: It is written that if $C$ is false, then do not choose any $\epsilon_0$. So $D$, which contains $\epsilon_0$ is meaningless

Comment: Ah I see. I thought you had an implicit $\forall$ in front of $\epsilon_0$ in $D$, but you're saying that the occurrence of $\epsilon_0$ in $D$ is in fact *free* and contingent on a selection based on $C$?