# Why is there only "T" and "F" in a truth table?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, foundations

Usually when creating a truth table containing two statements, we make four rows and two columns which we fill with T and F.

So, if there are $(n)$ statements, we make $(2^n)$ rows and $n$ columns which we fill with T and F.

However I have noted from [my this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119359/is-my-proof-of-uniqueness-of-limit-of-sequence-correct) the possibility that if a certain statement is true, the next statement is not a proposition OR if a certain statement is false, the next statement is not a proposition. This will make the "next statement" neither true nor false.

So there must be actually 3 varying entries (T,F,N/A) in a truth table and not two (T,F) as is usually done.

If the statement is a proposition and is true, then T

If the statement is a proposition and is false, then F

If the statement is not a proposition, then N/A

So, if there are $(n)$ statements, we should make $(3^n)$ rows and $n$ columns which we fill with T,F and N/A.

Comment: Why wouldn't $D$ be a proposition in your linked question? It's a fully formed sentence with no free variables

Comment: There is [many-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic) (term usually used when more than 2, but finitely many, truth values allowed) and [fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) (every real number between $0$ and $1$ can be a truth value) and (way more general then either of the previous) [Boolean-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean-valued_model) (the truth values range over any given complete Boolean algebra).

Comment: @AndrewL: Can we please go back to that question for a little chat?

Comment: It is written that if $C$ is false, then do not choose any $ϵ_0$. So $D$, which contains $ϵ_0$ is meaningless.